# Capturing power-off interrupt for i.MX6UL (linux kernel)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, device-tree, imx6

### Context

I'm using an i.MX6 (IMXULL) application processor, and want to know in software when the power-off button has been pressed:

Luckily, the IMX6ULL reference manual explains that this should be possible:

---

**Section 10.5: ONOFF Button**

> The chip supports the use of a **button input signal** to request main SoC power state changes (i.e. On or Off) from the PMU. The ONOFF logic inside of SNVS_LP allows for connecting directly to a PMIC or other voltage regulator device. The logic takes a button input signal and then outputs a `pmic_en_b` and `set_pwr_off_irq` signal. [...] The logic has two different modes of operation (Dumb and Smart mode).
> The Dumb PMIC Mode uses `pmic_en_b` to issue a level signal for on and off. Dumb pmic mode has many different configuration options which include (debounce, off to on time, and max time out).

(Also available in condensed form [here](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/IMX6ULIEC.pdf) on page 18)

---

### Attempt

Therefore, I have built a trivially simple kernel module to try and capture this interrupt:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("John Doe <j.doe@acme.inc>");


// Forward declaration
irqreturn_t irq_handler (int, void *);


// Number of interrupt to capture
#define INTERRUPT_NO        36


static int __init pwr_ctl_init (void)
{
    pr_err("init()\n");
    return request_irq(INTERRUPT_NO, irq_handler, IRQF_SHARED, "onoff-button",
        (void *)irq_handler);
}

static void __exit pwr_ctl_exit (void)
{
    pr_err("exit()\n");
    free_irq(INTERRUPT_NO, NULL);
}


irqreturn_t irq_handler (int irq, void *dev_irq)
{
    pr_err("interrupt!\n");
    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

module_init(pwr_ctl_init);
module_exit(pwr_ctl_exit);
```

---

### Problem

However, I cannot find any information about what the number of the interrupt is. When searching on the internet, all I get is this one NXP forum post:

- [ONOFF button doesn't interrupt](https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/ONOFF-button-doesn-t-interrupt/m-p/279466)

Which hints it should be `36`. However, I have found that this isn't the case on my platform. When I check `/proc/interrupts` 36 is already occupied by `20b4000.ethernet`. Because the application manual also mentions that it is generated by the `SNVS` low power system, I checked the device-tree and found the following information:

```
                snvs_poweroff: snvs-poweroff {
                    compatible = "syscon-poweroff";
                    regmap = <&snvs>;
                    offset = <0x38>;
                    value = <0x60>;
                    mask = <0x60>;
                    status = "disabled";
                };

                snvs_pwrkey: snvs-powerkey {
                    compatible = "fsl,sec-v4.0-pwrkey";
                    regmap = <&snvs>;
                    interrupts = <GIC_SPI 4 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
                    linux,keycode = <KEY_POWER>;
                    wakeup-source;
                    status = "disabled";
                };
```

This information seems useful for knowing that SNVS is the interrupt controller, but not how to capture this `set_pwr_off_irq` signal.

---

### Conclusion

- How do I capture the ON/OFF interrupt supposedly generated by SNVS?
- How do I determine the number of an interrupt from the device-tree (if applicable at all)
- Am I misunderstanding something about how the ONOFF feature works? Is it possible to capture this from a kernel module at all?

---

### Edit

This edit answers some user questions, and then goes into new information about the problem I have since discovered:

#### User Questions

- **Processor:** The processor is an `NXP i.MX 6UltraLite / 6ULL / 6ULZ` ARM Cortex A7.

#### New Information

- **SNVS Driver**: Using my build system kernel configuration, I have modified and verified that the `snvs_pwrkey` driver (see [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/input/keyboard/snvs_pwrkey.c)) is enabled. My modification consists of adding a *single* `kprint` statement to the interrupt routine to see if the button trips it. This did not work
- I have tried updating the driver to a newer version, which claims to support newer i.MX6 processors. This also did not work
- I have tried to load the driver as a *kernel module* for easier debugging. This is **not possible**, as the kernel configuration requires this be enabled and I cannot remove it from being statically built into the kernel.

Comment: Have you checked whether the `snvs_pwrkey` node is enabled in your board dts file? `snvs_pwrkey` node shown in your code is disabled (try enabling it by adding `&snvs_pwrkey{ status = "okay"; };` in your dts). Assuming that's the only issue, once you set it up correctly, you can capture the interrupt the same way the snvs_pwrkey.c driver does it if you want to do it in kernel space. If you want to capture it from user space, the snvs_pwrkey.c already does it for you by exposing it in the input subsystem, so you can access it just like any input from /dev/input/ or wherever it's mapped to.

Comment: @dhanushka Yeah, it is enabled. I feel like I've triple checked it. By default it is `disabled`, that's correct. But I've tried setting `status = "okay";` and also just removing the `status` line altogether. Nothing happens sadly. It's driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is rather anticlimactic. In short, there was a device-tree overlay that was *disabling* my changes to `snvs_pwrkey`, even when I had enabled it. Once I located and removed the overlay, the driver (`snvs_pwrkey.c`) was working as expected.

As for the IRQ number, it turns out that the IRQ for the power button is `45` as interpreted through Linux. The interrupt is not configured for sharing, so my kernel module could not be loaded.

If you want to capture power button toggle events, I suggest modifying the driver to add some output, and then perhaps adding a `udev` rule to capture button presses. I will update my answer with an example ASAP.